# Where is the configuration setting for enabling and disabling low voltage warnings in Bullseye 64 bit?

Tags: voltage

I'd like to know where the configuration settings are set for the Bullseye 64 bit Raspberry Pi OS to enable or disable low voltage warnings, for both the terminal and the LXDE desktop environment. It appears that previously this was set using an `avoid_warnings` flag in the file `/boot/config.txt` but this appears not to be the case today. So how is this configuration setting enabled and disabled today?

Please note that the aim here is to disable the warnings on the tty terminal, not merely to remove LXDE popup warnings.

Please note also that I don't need more basic recommendations to upgrade cables, power supplies, hardware etc. :)

Many thanks

Comment: Why don’t you want to fix the power issue?

Comment: @CoderMike It's not a question of want, there are certain security constraints on the hardware available for use. Hence why I said that I don't need hardware recommendations. Are you aware of the contemporary ways to enable and disable the warnings given that altering the hardware setup is not an option? Or would you know where that information might be found? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You fix it by getting an appropriate supply.

There is no way to disable it.

The low voltage is detected in hardware and actioned in firmware.

Answer (score -1):

Further investigation has shown that [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/97318/654589) appears to be a solution. It appears to suppress kernel messages:

```
sudo dmesg -n 1
```

Comment: This will not "disable low voltage warnings" - it merely suppresses console messages. The Lightning Bolt and error flags will remain. [Firmware Warning Icons](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#firmware-warning-icons)